# Python CSV File Gathering

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Looking for some support here. I have a Directory of many files. There are two types of files: Account_History and Milestone Files. Both Account_History and Milestone files have multiple exports to this directory on a given day. I don’t need all of the files each day, just the last file each day (for both Account_History and Milestone files) which in the naming convention typically ends with “_1500.csv”. Picture below to help detail this.

Now where things get challenging for me, some days there is a revision to the “_1500.csv” files. In this case, I wouldn’t want to pick up the original _1500.csv file for that day, instead I would need to pick up the “_1500_revision1.csv” file. I don’t need the revisions UNLESS it is “_1500_revision1.csv” .

From there, I’d like to combine all of these (concat function) into one dataframe for data analysis & data preparation. Thanks for any help in advance.

Picture below to help detail this.

[Example of the Directory I need to grab from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfqjL.jpg)

I attempted to do an “iloc” to grab the last file of the day but that was very random and did not work. I think what I may need is some type of conditioning statement.

“Grab every _1500.csv for each Milestone named csv UNLESS there is a _1500_revision1.csv for Milestone.

“Grab every _1500.csv for each Account_History named csv UNLESS there is a _1500_revision1.csv for Account_history.”

Comment: if you use `glob` to get a list of all files in the folder and then sort them, is the file you want always the last one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
import re

directory = '/your/path/here'

milestone_files = [item for item in os.listdir(directory) if item.startswith('milestone')]
history_files = [item for item in os.listdir(directory) if item.startswith('account_history')]

# Get a list of the days
milestone_days = list(set([f.split('_')[1] for f in milestone_files]))
history_days = list(set([f.split('_')[2] for f in history_files]))

milestone_dataframes = []
history_dataframes = []

for day in milestone_days:
    keep = sorted([f for f in milestone_files if day in f], reverse=True)[0]
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, keep))
    milestone_dataframes.append(temp_df)

for day in history_days:
    keep = sorted([f for f in history_files if day in f], reverse=True)[0]
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, keep))
    history_dataframes.append(temp_df)


milestone_df = pd.concat(milestone_dataframes)
history_df = pd.concat(history_dataframes)
```

I haven't actually tested it on a directory, so hopefully it will work!